# Why does my Golang Workerpool ignore jobs?

Tags: go, threadpool

I am trying to create a threadpool of workers that do jobs.

This seems to  working fine, but it if I, for instance, input 1-6. It won't print out six.

Can someone explain why and hopefully provide a fix for me?

```
// Golang Workerpool

func worker(id int, jobs <-chan string) {
    fmt.Println("Worker", id, "initilized!")
        for {
            s := <- jobs
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("Worker", id, "said:", s);
    }
}

func main() {
    // In order to use our pool of workers we need to send
    // them work and collect their results. We make 2
    // channels for this.
    jobs := make(chan string)

    // This starts up 3 workers, initially blocked
    // because there are no jobs yet.
    for w := 1; w <= 3; w++ {
        go worker(w, jobs)
    }

    for {
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        jobs <- text
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run your code I get all the output. You're reading as far as the newline character- are you hitting enter after the 6?

Comment: Yes, it prints out 1-5, but not 6. and it also sometimes skips inputs.

Comment: Are you sure missed inputs aren't just empty strings? If you just hit enter you get `Worker 1 said:` or equivalent

Comment: I know it's not much help, but I recorded my terminal output here so you can see how it behaves for me: https://asciinema.org/a/XjMKZ9uZF2eApcLl3PkVjEg4M I've got `go version go1.10 linux/amd64` on ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Try it like 5 times faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)` to just before the for loop

I would guess if this is run repeatedly the waiting data in stdin is lost

Answer (score 1):

Apparently making the channel a buffered channel helped.

```
jobs := make(chan string, 3)
```

Thanks guys